# Use variables within sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

If I have the following variables:

```
@q='minute'
@r=5
```

How can I use them in a query so it forms the following:

```
select CURRENT_TIME - interval 5 minute;
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
select CURRENT_TIME - interval @r @q;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use prepared statements to create dynamic queries like that:

```
set @q='minute';
set @r=5;
set @sql = concat("select CURRENT_TIME - interval ",@r," ", @q, " into @result_var;");

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

select @result_var;
```

The variable `@result_var` will contain the result of time calculation.

**Update:** prepared statements are not available on triggers but you can use standard `case when` statement if only have `minute` and `hour` for `@q` variable:

```
-- procedure body

set @q='hour';
set @r=5;

set @result_var = 0;

case  
    when @q = 'minute' then
      select CURRENT_TIME - interval @r minute into @result_var;
    when @q = 'hour' then
      select CURRENT_TIME - interval @r hour into @result_var;
end case;

select @result_var;

-- end procedure body
```

Again: The variable `@result_var` will contain the result of time calculation.

Comment: Is there any other way I can get this done? I want the code to be used within a trigger but dynamic sql isn't allowed in triggers or stored functions.

Comment: @DanielleS what would be the all variants of `@q` variable?

Comment: "minute" & "hour"

Comment: I'm looking into using the replace function. I'm working on it now.

Comment: @DanielleS I added additional code to avoid prepared statements, that code you can use inside a trigger without problems.